# Ordered union of two table types

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two table types **lv_crds_auto** and **lv_crds_manual**. They are specified like this:

```
TYPE t_crds IS RECORD(
  NAME    VARCHAR2(100),
  surname VARCHAR2(100),
  amount  NUMBER);

TYPE t_crds_data IS TABLE OF t_crds;
lv_crds_auto   t_crds_data;
lv_crds_manual t_crds_data;
```

I need a data set of both of those tables, but they must be ordered by amount.

For example, we have following values in tables:

[image]

I need to loop through those values, but they should be joined and sorted by amount value like this:

[image]

Could you please tell me how I could achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You want `UNION ALL`

```
select name,surname,amount from
(
  select name,surname,amount from lv_crds_auto 
    UNION ALL
  select name,surname,amount from lv_crds_manual
) ORDER BY amount
```

Note that if the amount is same, there is no way to ensure that say Ginta,  Maragaret,Ariana will always be 1st, 2nd and 3rd rows. You may need another column to `order by` to maintain a desired sequence in the query result.

Comment: The problem is that I don't have a really table with that data. lv_crds_auto and lv_crds_manual are filled with aggregated data from 10 tables